# Populae value of input into span....Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have an input, that you can increment up or down with a button.

I just want the number in that input field to populate a span.

```
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="balls" id="ballsLeft" value="48"/>
        </div>

<span id="ballsleftholder"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should seems like:

```
$('#ballsLeft').keyup(function() {
  $("#ballsleftholder").text($("#ballsLeft").val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on your `<input>` element and use one of the following:

---

[.html(htmlString)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$("#ballsleftholder").html($("#ballsLeft").val());
```

---

[.text(textString)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

> Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.

```
$("#ballsleftholder").text($("#ballsLeft").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to that input field and in that event do something like this

```
$('#ballsLeftHolder').html($(this).val());
```

You can also use `keyup`, `keydown` events. Just find what will exactly fit for your need.

Checkout this [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).